# Can not load related data with Include or ThenInclude or Select/Many with ONE query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

1 Test has 1 TestType assigned.

I need to load all TestType entities with relation to a Test OR not and Schoolclass , Subject and Assigned Pupils to a test (PupilsTests)

The .SelectMany or .Select fails here during runtime.

I tried different combinations of Include and ThenInclude but no chance to get the Tests WITH the PupilsTests.

I can only get the PupilsTests with the Tests when I start my query with the `context.Tests`

but that has the consequence that I get only the TestTypes assigned to a Test
 - *innerjoin* - but I need all TestTypes and their Tests and their PupilsTests and I want it in ONE query.

```
var testtypes = await context.TestTypes
                   .Include(x => x.Schoolclass)
                   .Include(x => x.Subject)
                   .Include(x => x.Tests.SelectMany(z => z.PupilsTests))
              .Where(t => t.SchoolyearId == schoolyearId)
              .AsNotTracking()
              .ToListAsync();



        public class TestType
{
    public TestType()
    {
        Tests = new HashSet<Test>();
    }
    // Props removed for clarity
    public int Id { get; set; }   
    public ISet<Test> Tests { get; set; }
    public Schoolyear Schoolyear { get; set; }  
    public Schoolclass Schoolclass { get; set; }   
    public Subject Subject { get; set; }
    public int SchoolyearId { get; set; }
}

  public class Test
    {
        public Test()
        {
            PupilsTests = new HashSet<PupilTest>();
        }
        // Props removed for clarity
        public int Id { get; set; }           
        public ISet<PupilTest> PupilsTests { get; set; }
        public TestType TestType { get; set; }


    }
```

Comment: By idea `.Include(x => x.Tests.SelectMany(z => z.PupilsTests))` should be `.Include(x => x.Tests).ThenInclude(x => x.PupilsTests)`. What's the result in such case? And what EF Core version are you on?

Comment: No.. the .ThenInclude(x => x.NothinghereOnlyLinqMethods). I use EF Core     "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",

Comment: It might be Intellisense issue. Try typing what I wrote in the first comment.

Comment: Damn... I had that intellisense problem a year ago I remember. And yes your hint worked!  I get now my data in one query! I forgot what was the root cause of this. I mean this "bug" is old... You have any idea wether a bug fix for this is filed at M$ ? Thanks and please create a solution with your advise!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The EF Core equivalent syntax of EF6

```
.Include(x => x.Tests.SelectMany(z => z.PupilsTests))
```

is

```
.Include(x => x.Tests).ThenInclude(x => x.PupilsTests)
```

Note that there seems to be a VS Intellisense issue inside the `ThenInclude`, so just type the above and it will compile successfully and work.

Also please note that EF Core processes collection includes differently (does not use single query as in EF6), so the above would generate and execute 3 SQL queries.

**Update:** The VS Intellisense issue now is specifically mentioned in the EF Core documentation under [Including multiple levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels) section:

> **Note!**
>
> Current versions of Visual Studio offer incorrect code completion options and can cause correct expressions to be flagged with syntax errors when using the `ThenInclude` method after a collection navigation property. This is a symptom of an IntelliSense bug tracked at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8237. It is safe to ignore these spurious syntax errors as long as the code is correct and can be compiled successfully.

Comment: `Intellisense` note, very helpful, consider highlighting it.

Comment: @AntonToshik Sure. Now it is even documented - see the **Note** inside  [Including multiple levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels)