# Querying related entities with Eager & Explicit loading it doesn't work in EF for ASP.NET MVC CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core

I tried this in **VS 2015 .net MVC Application** and it works perfectly without any trouble.

Instead, trying to test the same with DOTNET CORE 1.x, I can't get the 2^ level navigation property . You've got a situation like that or you know how solve?

**DATABASE CLASS**

```
 public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }

        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public Person Person { get; set; }  

        public Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }   // I need to show this in the partial view
        public string Action { get; set; }
    }
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
     public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }


        Blog blog = await _context.Blogs
            .Include(b=>b.Posts)
            .Include(b=>b.Posts.Select(x=>x.Person))    
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.BlogId == id);

            //Then.Include  don't show property!


        if (blog == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(blog);
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
@model MyProj.Models.Blog

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Blog</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Url)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Url)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.BlogId }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
<br />
<div>
    @Html.Partial("_posts", this.Model.Posts)
</div>
```

**PARTIAL VIEW**

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProj.Models.Post>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content)
        </th>
        <th>
            Person
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Person.Username)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.PostId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.PostId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.PostId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

**In my case I cannot get the property Person.Username in a partial that show post list. ThenIclude (with intellisense) don't show the table**

**Error code :**
InvalidOperationException: The property expression 'b => {from Post x in [b].Posts select [x].Person}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

**Thanks in advance for troubleshooting, I can't figure it out.**

Comment: EF Core has differences and incompatibilities with EF6. For EF Core you should use `.Include(b => b.Posts).ThenInclude(x => x.Person)` - 
see [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Comment: I already tried this but, as described above, intellisense don't show the entity (person). Thanks anyway

Comment: He-he, it's Intellisense problem. Copy/paste the above - it will compile and work :) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41129970/can-not-load-related-data-with-include-or-theninclude-or-select-many-with-one-qu/41130631#41130631

Comment: I will do! I'm outside home now. Merry Xmas ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to solve this for about 20 hours to understand why it doesn't work..... At end it was egg of Columbus. Thanks to Ivan Stoev for the comment.

**Though intellisense doesn't show the related entities, when the app is builded it works.**

```
 Blog blog = await _context.Blogs
            .Include(b=>b.Posts)
                .ThenInclude(p=>p.Person)  
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.BlogId == id);
```