# ThenInclude not working for an Entity Framework LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a database model like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId{ get; set; }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So we have a customer which can do an order. This order includes a product and this includes a name. I'm now trying to return the complete model with a linq statement like the following:

```
_db.Customer.Include(c => c.Orders).ThenInclude(o => o.Product).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

But `ThenInclude(o => o.Product)` doesn't function because Orders is an ICollection. Greetings from Germany and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `ThenInclude()` is a feature of EF Core, are you using that?

Comment: Yes, using the latest version of EF Core with .Net Core

Comment: And what is not working? The code snippet you've posted should work.

Answer (score 8):

To load related entities in EF 6 you should use `Select` method as I show below:

```
_db.Customer.Include(c => c.Orders.Select(o=>o.Product)).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

[`ThenInclude`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) method was added in EF Core, which is the last version of EF.

Comment: The **old** way? OP is either on EF6 and this is the **only** way, or is on EF Core and this is not supported at all :)

Comment: Yes, but I thought he was using EF Core, that's why I called that way

Comment: Then you've got a problem because EF Core does not support the "old way".

Comment: Are you sure? To be honest I haven't tested recently but in the last beta version was supported

Comment: Yes, I am. Many things have changed since beta versions (although they better be called alpha, and current - beta:), event between the official 1.0 and 1.1 (latest).

Comment: ok, I will update my answer then, thanks for the info @IvanStoev

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41129970/can-not-load-related-data-with-include-or-theninclude-or-select-many-with-one-qu/41130631#41130631. Take care.

Comment: Yes, I tried your answer but got the following error:

System.InvalidOperationException: The property expression 'c => {from Order o in [c].Orders select [o].Product}' is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

May be wrong here but wouldn;t you need to change:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

to

```
public class Order
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

in order for this to behave the way you are expecting.